# Generate output file Python

Tags: python, list, output

As it can be seen in the code. I created two output files one for output after splitting
and second output as actual out after removing duplicate lines
How can i make only one output file. Sorry if i sound too stupid, I'm a beginner

```
import sys
txt = sys.argv[1] 

lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
actualout = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in open(txt, "r"):
    line = line.split("?", 1)[0]
    outfile.write(line+"\n")
outfile.close()

for line in open("out.txt", "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        actualout.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)

actualout.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the lines from the input file directly into the set. Since sets cannot have duplicates, you don't even need to check for those. Try this:

```
import sys
txt = sys.argv[1] 

lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
actualout = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in open(txt, "r"):
    line = line.split("?", 1)[0]
    lines_seen.add(line + "\n")

for line in lines_seen:
    actualout.write(line)

actualout.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first step you iterate through every line in the file, split the line on your decriminator and store it into a list. After that you iterate through the list and write it into your output file.

```
import sys
txt = sys.argv[1] 

lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
actualout = open("output.txt", "w")

data = [line.split("?", 1[0] for line in open("path/to/file/here", "r")]
for line in data:
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        actualout.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)  

actualout.close()
```

Comment: Its showing error in data variable where you tried to close the list